# A Continuous Stochastic Process

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Take $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and sequence $(\Gamma^m_k(\cdot))_{m\ge 1, 2^m \ge k \ge 1}$ of independent Guassian random variables with $\Gamma^m_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2^{-m})$.

Consider now a sequence of discrete-time stochastic processes $(W_m(\cdot, t))_{m\ge 1, t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ defined as follows (a.s. for each $\omega \in \Omega, m \ge 1$ and $0\le k < 2^m$):

- $W_m(\omega, 0) = 1$
- $W_m(\omega,t) = W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k) \ \ \forall t \in (2^{-m}k,2^{-m}(k+1))$
- $W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k) - W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}(k+1)) = \begin{cases}
  0 &\text{ if } W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k) = 0\\[0.5em]
  2^{-m} & \text{ if } \Gamma_k^m(\omega) \le 2^{-m}\\[0.5em]
  (l+1)2^{-m} & \text{ if } \Gamma_k^m(\omega) \in (l2^{-m}, (l+1)2^{-m}] \text{ for } 1\le l < 2^m W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k)\\[0.5em]
  W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k) &\text{ if } \Gamma_k^m (\omega)> W_m(\omega, 2^{-m}k)
  \end{cases}$

An intuitive interpretation (that is not meant to be taken seriously) of this process could be that there is a descending ladder starting from $y=1$ and a ball that falls down the stairs, and each time it reaches a step, there is a probability that it skips some of the subsequent steps (bouncing over them).
My question is:

- What can we say about the limit process $W_\infty$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$? (And in which sense it is a limit?)
- Does this process $W_\infty$ (in case exists) reminds you anything known?
- What if we said $\Gamma^m_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2^{-2m})$?

Thanks

Comment: Simulation suggests that $W_{\infty}(t)=0$ for $t>0$ when $\Gamma^m_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2^{-m})$, and $t\mapsto W_{\infty}(t)$ is linearly decreasing (with a deterministic slope) when $\Gamma^m_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,2^{-2m})$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yeah, I got the same results right now

Comment: Note that your recurrence relation is simplified as $$W_m(2^{-m}(k+1)) = 0 \vee \bigl( W_m(2^{-m}k) - \tilde{\Gamma}^m_k \bigr), $$ where $$ \tilde{\Gamma}^m_k = \frac{1+0\vee\lfloor 2^m \Gamma^m_k\rfloor}{2^m}. $$ That is, $W_m$ is essentially a random walk with negative drifts when it stays above $0$. So the simulation results are not unexpected in light of LLN.